# Capturing Non-Standard Powershell CmdLet Output for Flow Control

Tags: version-control, tfs, powershell

Currently trying to build a script utilizing cmdlets from the MS released "Team Foundation Server Power Tools" package.

I'm attempting to flow command logic from the success or failure of the "**Update-TfsWorkspace**" cmdlet however I can't seem get a return code out of the call nor can I capture the output using Out-String.  I'm using Powershell v1.

```
update-tfsworkspace "C:\doesnotexist\" -recurse -version T
```

Yields a message of "Unable to determine the workspace." which is the error I'm trying to catch.

```
$ret = update-tfsworkspace "C:\doesnotexist\" -recurse -version T
```

Is expected to give me a $true/$false indicating success/fail but doesn't work.

```
update-tfsworkspace "C:\doesnotexist\" -recurse -version T | Out-Null
```

Is expected to prevent the cmdlet from writing the message but doesn't work.

```
trap{echo "fail"}
update-tfsworkspace $workspace_path -recurse -version T
```

Is expected to catch an error and write "fail" but doesn't work.

```
$msg = update-tfsworkspace $workspace_path -recurse -version T | Out-String
```

Is expected to populate a $msg variable with the host output but doesn't work.

I'm totally out of ideas here.  Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't have TFS so I can't test so I won't post this as an answer. Does that commandlet support the -ErrorAction and/or -ErrorVariable parameters? This may be a direction that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little hacky, but since I don't have TFS to try to figure something else out, see if [this](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6926.entry) helps.

Comment: As mentioned the following is able to access the cmdlet output:
PS> powershell.exe -noprofile -file test.ps1 > test.log
PS> Get-Content test.log

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this cmdlet wasn't written correctly.  First, since it didn't succeed it should have emitted an error object which would have caused $? to return false which you could have checked or trapped.  Second, you can't suppress the error message using -ea 0.  It looks like this snapin is using the Host api to write an error string to the host console.  That's a spew!!  For now, you could do what EBGreen suggests:

$msg = powershell.exe -nologo update-tfsworkspace "C:\doesnotexist\" -recurse -version T 2>&1

Just watch out for all the text your profile script spits out when a new instance of PowerShell starts up.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that the cmdlet is writing an error (Non-Terminating Error), but not throwing an exception (Terminating Error).  You can make it throw an exception by adding the ErrorAction parameter:

```
trap{echo "fail"}
update-tfsworkspace $workspace_path -recurse -version T -ErrorAction "Stop"
```

This will cause the cmdlet to make all errors terminating (throwing an exception if it writes to the error stream).

Comment: This is awesome. Just what I was looking for today. Thanks so much.